# After load event for iframe?

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I'm using an iframe as target for one of my forms. I need to transform the html of the iframe once the form is submitted. I tried using the onload event, but when the event is fired, my iframe does not have the html resulting from my form yet (right on the debugger breakpoint):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        function loaded(){
            var lResponse = document.getElementById('results');
            debugger;
        }   
    </script>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <form id="serverForm" target="results" <web:taskProcessorName attribute="action"  type="admin"/>>
                        <div>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div name="resultsDiv" id="resultsDiv" style="display: none">
                                            <iframe name="results" id="results" onload="loaded" frameborder="0"></iframe>                                           
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Hidden Inputs -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="server" value="..." /> 
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById('serverForm').submit();
        document.getElementById('resultsDiv').style.display='block';        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No 3rd party library - pure javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the following instead and that seems to catch the event when the iframe html is set already:

```
function lLoadFunc(){
    var lResponse = document.getElementById('results');
}

if(lResponse.addEventListener)
    lResponse.addEventListener('load', lLoadFunc, true);
```